# Create VIEW with two different queries and same table having PIVOT but one additional different column

Tags: sql, merge, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to MERGE two queries which are generating two pivots i.e pivot1 and pivot2( trying to merge two pivots)
I am having two different queries let's say query1 and query2.

> Query1 is as follows:

```
select 
   COLUMN_B,
   NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,
   NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,
   NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3
FROM
   (
   SELECT COLUMN_B,COLUMN_C,COLUMN_D,
   FROM BASE_TABLE
   WHERE COLUMN_B IN ('DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B, DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B, DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B')
   )
pivot
   (
    sum(COLUMN_D)
    for(COLUMN_C)
    IN ('COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1' AS CP1,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2' AS CP2,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3' AS CP3)
   )
ORDER BY COLUMN_B;
```

> Query1 OUTPUT(pivot1):

```
COLUMN_B            CP1 CP2 CP3
DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B   12  23  34
DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B   45  56  67
DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B   78  89  98
```

> Query2 is as follows:

```
select 
   COLUMN_A,
   COLUMN_B,
   NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,
   NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,
   NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3
FROM
   (
   SELECT COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,COLUMN_C,COLUMN_D,
   FROM BASE_TABLE
   WHERE 
     COLUMN_A IN ('DATA1_IN_COLUMN_A, DATA2_IN_COLUMN_A, DATA3_IN_COLUMN_A', DATA4_IN_COLUMN_A', 
                  DATA5_IN_COLUMN_A')
     COLUMN_B IN ('DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B, DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B, DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B') 
   )
pivot
   (
    sum(COLUMN_D)
    for(COLUMN_C)
    IN ('COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1' AS CP1,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2' AS CP2,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3' AS CP3)
   )
ORDER BY COLUMN_A;
```

> Query2 OUTPUT(pivot2):

```
COLUMN_A            COLUMN_B            CP1 CP2 CP3
DATA1_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B   12  23  34
DATA2_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B   45  56  67
DATA3_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B   78  89  98
DATA4_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B   21  32  54
```

Is there any way that I can append both outputs like below?

```
 COLUMN_A              COLUMN_B         CP1 CP2 CP3
Nothing here        DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B   12  23  34
Nothing here        DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B   45  56  67
Nothing here        DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B   78  89  98
DATA1_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B   12  23  34
DATA2_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B   45  56  67
DATA3_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B   78  89  98
DATA4_IN_COLUMN_A   DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B   21  32  54
```

IF not then what is an alternative to achieve this output as output order cannot be compromised.
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach might be to `union all` both queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        NULL AS COLUMN_A,
        COLUMN_B,
        NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,
        NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,
        NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3
    FROM (
        SELECT COLUMN_B,COLUMN_C,COLUMN_D,
        FROM BASE_TABLE
        WHERE COLUMN_B IN ('DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B', 'DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B', 'DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B')
    )
    PIVOT (
        SUM(COLUMN_D)
        FOR(COLUMN_C)
        IN ('COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1' AS CP1,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2' AS CP2,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3' AS CP3)
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        COLUMN_A,
        COLUMN_B,
        NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1,
        NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2,
        NVL(COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3,0) AS COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3
    FROM (
        SELECT COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,COLUMN_C,COLUMN_D,
        FROM BASE_TABLE
        WHERE 
            COLUMN_A IN ('DATA1_IN_COLUMN_A', 'DATA2_IN_COLUMN_A', 'DATA3_IN_COLUMN_A', 'DATA4_IN_COLUMN_A', 'DATA5_IN_COLUMN_A')
            AND COLUMN_B IN ('DATA1_IN_COLUMN_B', 'DATA2_IN_COLUMN_B', 'DATA3_IN_COLUMN_B') 
    )
    PIVOT (
        sum(COLUMN_D)
        for(COLUMN_C)
        IN ('COLUMN_IN_PIVOT1' AS CP1,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT2' AS CP2,'COLUMN_IN_PIVOT3' AS CP3)
    )
) x
ORDER BY COLUMN_A NULLS FIRST, COLUMN_B;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. This helped me half away, can you help me to maintain the order of output.